# REQUEST: Children laughing/singing/babbling

Tags: sound-effects, request, recording, exchange

Hey,

Would anybody here happen to have recordings of children babbling/laughing/chatting away?
More specifically aged between 4 and 12?

Will swap sounds you send me for recordings of a football game here in Zürich (lots of cool chanting, jeering, booing)

Anybody interested?

Kurt

Comment: What language do you want it in? I have children playing, chatting and singing but it is in mixed zulu/Khosa. 

Comment: Sorry for being totally dof...It needs to be in German.. I'm meeting a female friend a bit later on who I think I can cheat the recording with. Thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kurt

It seems like you have this covered now.

However if you need more recordings, I have some German primary school kids from Hamburg on my site, Airborne Sound ([www.airbornesound.com](http://www.airbornesound.com)).

http://www.airbornesound.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=germany%20primary%20school

They are a small handful of ambiences, recorded with an H4n at various distances.  Some are interiors, some are exteriors.

Paul